# Строка начиналась с цифры или буквы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Помогите составить выражение, чтоб строка начиналась с цифры или буквы. И потом могли быть пробелы, цифры буквы

```
(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\ ]*$/) - не подошло
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же уже задавали этот вопрос пару часов назад.

? -   Знак вопроса означает 0 или 1 раз, то же самое, что и {0,1}. Например, «colou?r» соответствует и color, и colour.

* -  Звёздочка означает **0**, 1 или любое число раз ({0,}). Например, «go*gle» соответствует **ggle**, gogle, google и др.

+ - Плюс означает **хотя бы 1 раз** ({1,}). Например, «go+gle» соответствует gogle, google и т. д. (**но не ggle**).

В предыдущем вопросе вас посылали в гугл. Я не буду этого делать. Понимаю что гугл большой и выучить регулярочки не самое простое занятие. Так что в моем ответе(выше) вы увидите ту информацию, которая поможет вам решить вашу задачу. И если уж с этим вы не сможете разобрать то у меня для вас плохие новости...